# Add #anchor to next/previous_post_link

Tags: next-post-link, previous-post-link

I have tried to figure out to change the `previous_post_link` by following the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/next_post_link) but I can't figure it out.
Same for the `next_post_link`.

I just want to have a simple link but with an `#anchor` tag added.

All I get is a changed LinkName - the url stays untouched.

I could do it with javascript, but this isn't the way I want to do it - I would like to know how to do it with WordPress tools.

Any hint would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to do the trick:

```
add_filter( 'next_post_link',     'wpse_post_link', 10, 4 );
add_filter( 'previous_post_link', 'wpse_post_link', 10, 4 );

function wpse_post_link( $output, $format, $link, $post )
{
    if( $url = get_permalink( $post ) ) 
        $output = str_replace( $url, $url . '#anchor', $output );

    return $output;
}
```

i.e. appending the `#anchor` to the previous/next permalinks.

ps: I removed the [`WP_Rewrite::using_permalink()`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/rewrite.php#L748) check, since we actually don't need it, `example.tld?p=123#anchor` should work as well.

Comment: hi birgire - thanks a bunch - that worked. Thanks also for editing my post. I swear, I will do better the next time. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome, sure no problem ;-)